# NFC unavailable when camera is open

Tags: android, android-camera, nfc

This is my Torch app:

```
final Camera.Parameters p;
Camera camera=Camera.open();

camera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));
p = camera.getParameters();

p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(p);
camera.startPreview();
```

When my app is running, some devices cannot detect NFC tags.  I noticed this happens with the Nexus 5X, specifically.

It appears certain devices can't detect NFC when the camera is running.

Can this problem be solved programmatically?

Comment: I don't see this on my Samsung S3. You may try the app "NFC Developer". This app combines camera and NFC

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, but I sincerely hope Nexus 5X is the only device on which you will ever encounter this.

The reason is that pretty late in the development cycle of the 5X, it was found that the NFC controller polling introduced noise in the camera sensor. The only feasible fix at that time was to turn off NFC when the camera is opened :(

Comment: Nexus 5X is not the only device, because it is the second device that I encounter this. But I forgot which is the first device.

Comment: This is happening to me on an LG G5 as well. Unable to scan any NFC tags while the camera preview is open.

Comment: The same problem occurs on a Samsung XCover 4 with Android 8.1. I can't even scan 20-30 seconds after the usage of the camera.

Comment: Can confirm that this is also a problem on the OnePlus 5 and HTC U11. Once the camera is active, the nfc module is deactivated.

Comment: I can confirm that problem on Nokia 6.1 too.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this yet? This problem is occurring on a Samsung XCover 4 with Android 9.5. Thanks

Comment: Happens on my Pixel 1 XL as well

Comment: Any Samsung with Android 11 has this issue

Comment: Confirming Samsung S10e and Note10 with Android 11 having this issue. Our production app that depends on camera and NFC simultaneously just broke because of a system update from 10 to 11.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem you can add this little code to your onStop, in the activity that uses the camera. If you need NFC, in some devices you need to release the camera.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try
    {
        android.hardware.Camera mCamera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "init_camera: " + e);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is working, beacause somo devices has the NFC reader chip in the camera. If you release the camera the NFC is ok in the next screen.

Comment: Except that it's not solving the problem of being able to use the NFC /and/ the camera at the same time. It's shutting down the camera so that you can use the NFC. That's a workaround, not a solution, that isn't ideal for an application that needs video at the same time as scanning NFC tags.

Comment: ok, thats true. For me, this was solved the problem in my application.