# Android: NFC detection when camera preview is on

Tags: android, android-camera, nfc

I have a qr/barcode scanner in my application and NFC detection.
The NFC detection works fine. I receive the onNewIntent in my Activity.

The issue is that this method isn't called anymore when I have my barcode scanner active.

After debugging, I found that it stops detecting nfc when I call:

```
mCamera.startPreview();
```

The Camera is used in a Fragment, which is added to the Activity.
This is a strange issue.

Is it possible to detect NFC and having the camera open + preview at the same time?

Edit
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34678864/1723525
This issue was on my Nexus 5X. No clue if this will be an issue for only this device or more devices..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is normally possible to have camera open and detect NFC at the same time. I have it working with ZXing in more than one project.

Comment: I do not have one for testing.

Comment: This did not work for me on an LG G5. Once the camera is on, NFC stops reading tags.