# NFC stops working on Device after Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-camera, nfc

I'm working on an App that takes photos and scans NFC Tags. The NFC Tag scanning works fine until I take a photo (via camera intent).

What I do:

In onResume() I call setupForegroundDispatch() and in onPause() I call stopForegroundDispatch().

```
public static void setupForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activity.getClass());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity, 0, intent, 0);
    adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, null, null);
}

public static void stopForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
    adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity);
}
```

To start the camera I call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                imageCaptureUri);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
```

To sum it up:

- The activity starts and in onResume() setupForgroundDispatch() will be called.
- scanning of NFC Tags works as expected
- I click a Button to start the camera via Intent

  - If I don't take a photo and go back to my activity -> NFC works well
  - If I take a picture and onActivityResult() will be called -> NFC does not work for about 20-30 seconds and then starts working again. I mean NFC stops working on the whole device, not only in the app. I can take a photo, then resume to my activity, then remove the app from recents and NFC does not work for the mentioned 20-30 Seconds. Then starts working again.

What I tried

- I checked that stopForegroundDispatch() will be called before the camera starts and that setupForegroundDispatch() will be called after the camera is done
- I removed my code from onActivityResult() to ensure that any further code interferes with the NFC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NFC is not available when I opened camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607168/nfc-is-not-available-when-i-opened-camera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have run into this

[NFC is not available when I opened camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607168/nfc-is-not-available-when-i-opened-camera)

Maybe you should try with a different device, if you have one