# React Native App NFC Issue When RNCamera Using with this

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, camera, nfc

I have facing issue when i am using RNCamera and NFC Manager both libraries simultaneously. The exactly issue i coming that if RNCamera open then NFC manager is not working or not scanning any Tag.

1-import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';
library- npm i react-native-nfc-manager

2-import NfcManager, {NfcTech} from 'react-native-nfc-manager';
library- npm i react-native-nfc-manager

I am expecting that both library or code working simultaneously.Like when RNCamera is open then  NFC Scan do also work.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/34678864/2373819 it seems some hardware manufacturers disable NFC when the camera is on because it generates noise on their multi mega pixel cameras.